# custom ports in google load balancer for IPv6

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, ipv6

I am running an MQTT (on custom port) server on the google compute engine. I need it to run on IPv6 network. After looking at the google docs (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6) I figured out we need to use TCP load balancer to support IPv6.

Now the TCP load balancer does not support my custom port 19004

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet. You can only use one of the [supported ports](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers):

> 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, 3389, 5222, 5432, 5671, 5672, 5900, 5901, 6379, 8085, 8099, 9092, 9200, and 9300

You'd have to either change the port or switch to IPv4.

Support for IPv6 on Virtual Machines has been already requested, you can follow this Feature Request [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/35904387).

Comment: Hello @Chetankumar and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!